Clustering Mixed Data Types: Algorithm Selection, Distance Measurement, and Feature Weighting
I have a database of 74,000 records with 29 features. Fourteen of these features are categorical and are either 0 or 1, while the other 15 features are continuous and have been normalized and scaled between 0 and 1. I have also performed some data cleaning and removed about 0.4% of the data to eliminate outliers. I want to run a clustering model to divide the data into 3 or 4 clusters. I have the following questions:

What algorithm should I use given that I have a fairly large database with both categorical and continuous features?
How should I measure the distance between features when I have both categorical and continuous features?
Three of these features are more important, and I want to assign them more weight. How much weight should I use?

